# How can i sign in with the credentials created in Authentication section of firebase in my React Web App?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have created following code structure as like and file:

> firebase.js
> app initialized with appropriate header files.
> also, auth exported with appropriate header file.

sigin.js
here i have called out the auth from firebase.js

> there, in a function i used following code to check:
>
> auth.signWithEmailAndPassword('abc@gmail.com', 'pass123') .then(()=>
> console.log('user is auth') .catch(err=> console.log(err))

But i am getting post error 400,  https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=undefined in my console log.
Dear, coders please give some kind suggestions!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a key piece on the call to firebase,

> Web API Key

. you can find it under your project settings, and add it to the firebase request.

Also, the firebase documentation gets updated often, and it's a good practice to revisit documentation frequently.

New Post API request for signIn

> [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API_KEY]](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=%5BAPI_KEY%5D)

on the body, you can attach the

> email,password,return secure token

.

Reference => https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password

Comment: thanks for the instant message, gone through the code and found my firebase api key was not properly connected due to the reference created in my .env file. Now working well!! anyway thanks alot for the review bro!